# How to autoplay music in android

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

Basically, I have a music player and I want it to auto play the next song after the first song finishes. This is what I coded so far but am not sure what more to add so that it works. I've tried to call the method that plays the next song but it gave me a parameter error. Why is that so?

```
private void gracefullyStopWhenMusicEnds() {
    player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            next(view);
        }
    });
}


public void next(View view)
{
    Song nextSong = SongCollection.getNextSong(songId);

    if ( nextSong != null)
    {
        songId = nextSong.getId();
        title = nextSong.getTitle();
        artist = nextSong.getArtist();
        fileLink = nextSong.getFileLink();
        coverArt = nextSong.getCoverArt();

        url = BASE_URL + fileLink;
        displaySong(title,artist,coverArt);
        stopActivities();
        playOrPauseMusic(view);
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help given.

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)